# no module named AppConfig

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I'm trying to run a server on my computer in Python/Django. In my installed_apps, I had a program called csvimport. It didn't work, so I had to install django-csvimport and I had to change it to csvimport.app.AppConfig in my installed-apps. However, I still get an importerror message saying "no module named AppConfig". (my version of django is 1.8, and django-csvimport is 2.4, by the way) Is this not the correct way to have csvimport in my installed_apps and my program?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`AppConfig` is Django's base class for the configuration class of custom apps, not necessarily the name of the config class of the app. But you're almost there:

[`csvimport.app.CSVImportConf`](https://github.com/edcrewe/django-csvimport/blob/master/csvimport/app.py#L5)

Comment: I already tried CSVImportConf and it gives me the same importerror (no module named CSVImportConf). Is there something else I should be adding?

Comment: In that case you can use the app name alone `csvimport` in the `INSTALLED_APPS` (guessing that version does not have a config class)

Comment: Okay, I tried putting both csvimport and django-csvimport into my installed_apps and neither time worked. I'm really sorry, I just don't understand how this isn't working. do I need to add other things in my settings.py (template_context_processors or middleware_classes, maybe?) file or to other files (urls.py) to get this to work? I had to do that with other apps I was trying to install

Comment: Where is the `csvimport` program coming from?

Comment: I used pip to install django-csvimport, buecause it wouldn't install just csvimport. Other than that I'm not sure.